# How to dynamically resize back-ground image inside a container element?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a webpage (using bootstrap) and in one of my container tag I am trying to set a background image, and i want this image to dynamically resize according to the screen size (without being cropped). I have used the following html and CSS code.

**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--Main stylesheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row new-class">
            <div class="col-xs-12 new">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--some more code here-->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery Easing -->
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Main JS -->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.new-class 
{max-width: 4368px;}

.new {
      padding-top: 63.227%;
      height: 150.24px;
      background-image: url("/images/9087.jpg");
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
     }
```

This code does that.
But the problem occurs when i try to make background-attachment as fixed, it makes the image big and the image gets cropped and blurred.
My original image size is 4368*2912 px.

Comment: Did you try in class new writing 'width:100%; height:auto;'

Comment: @RamSegev I tried that also but the same problem persists.

Comment: Is your intent for the image to be a full site back ground image? Based on the background-attachment: fixed; I'm guessing that's your intent?

Comment: @Culyx no i don't want my image to be a full site background. I just want it to be a background for the header section.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the header to be a static element on the page from the sound of things? i.e. the header does not move at all when the user scrolls? If that's the case try this:

```
html{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body{
    height: 100%;
}
.container{
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-image: url("/images/9087.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Using above solution, the image is becoming small (it is not covering the entire width of the screen) and if I make background-size as cover then the image is getting cropped.

Comment: Cover will stretch to the maximum image size, where as the contain will only match the minimum of either height/width while preserving aspect ratio